# Flutter The screen comes out well in flutter debug mode, but not in release mode

Tags: flutter

The screen comes out well in flutter debug mode, but not in release mode

[image]

debug mode.Show all the screen UI

[image]

release mode Screen UI completely disappeared

No touch response in release mode
My status..

```
pubspec.yaml
get: ^4.6.6
camera: ^0.10.5+9
permission_handler: ^11.3.0
google_fonts: ^6.1.0
image_picker: ^1.0.7
tflite_v2: ^1.0.0
animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
share_plus: ^7.2.2
screenshot: ^2.1.0
flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.13
google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
```

```
plugins {
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}
```

```
android
compileSdk 34
minSdkVersion 28
```

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4170], locale ko-KR)
Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.3)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the
      "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
Android Studio (version 2022.3)
VS Code (version 1.87.2)
Connected device (3 available)
Network resources
If you flutter run in release mode
An error like this came out
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

In settings.grade, I switched id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false, 1.8.0 and 1.6.0, but there was no other response

I tried a new project, but the same result came out

Comment: Mark require some more data to understand the issue. Can you try it in Profile mode to see if its working fine or not.

Also, try to add error widget inside MaterialApp -> Builder which can showcase the issue of what might be failing

Answer (score 0):

Check in the console in debug mode is there any warning or issue , if yes need to resolve. Sometimes it will not work properly in release mode if the code is not properly handled.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No issue occurs in debug mode.